# Angular Js redirect with toast message

Tags: angularjs, html, toast

when I click a button on a html with angular page I need to redirect to other. 
I use a javascript function and into it I call $location.path('/newValue')
This work fine, but I can't see toast page 1 success message.
I need show toast message and redirect to page (or show toast message, wait 1 second and redirect to page). 
How I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post some code ?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far. Post your code or create a fiddle and link it.

Comment: I have $http.get() call in  success I have toastr.success('Success') and $location.path('/newValue')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
toastr.info("Toast message here...");    
$timeout(function() {
    $location.path('/newValue');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)